# Well defined operations on vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am in the process of studying for a calc 3 exam and on all of the past exams there is a question like "Which of the following is a well-defined operation on vectors?" and I have no idea what this means, the only thing in the lecture notes I have been able to find was a footnote and google is turning up nothing for vectors. Thanks in advance

Comment: An operation is well-defined if it gives the same result when the representation of the input is changed without changing the value of the input.  A vector could be an equivalence class of ordered pairs of points.  Well-defined means you get the same answer no matter which representative of the class you choose

Comment: so a x (b x c) is a well-defined operation, but why isn't a • (b • c)?

Comment: because dot product is defined for vectors; $b\cdot c$ is well-defined, but the result is a scalar, so the dot product is not defined for it

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a lifesaver

Comment: You are welcome.  I would suggest that you edit your question to include your clarification of it in your comment (why is $a\times (b\times c)$ well defined but $a\cdot (b\cdot c)$ is not?); otherwise people might think the question was asking something more along the lines of what I answered with my first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v, w, $ and $u$ are vectors, then $v\times w$ is a vector and $v\cdot w$ is a scalar.

Therefore, $a\times(b\times c)$ is well defined as the cross product of two vectors, $a$ and $b\times c$,

but $a\cdot(b\cdot c)$ is not well defined as the dot product of two vectors, because $b \cdot c$ is not a vector --

$b \cdot c$ is a scalar.

Comment: by the way, $a\cdot (b\times c)$ is also well defined